# unable to write to a file char pointer

Tags: c++

i am writing a character pointer to a file, but my program always crashes at name when i do it and i am unable to figure out why

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "AmaProduct.h"

using namespace std;
namespace sict{
AmaProduct::AmaProduct(char file){
    fileTag_ = file;
}
const char* AmaProduct::unit()const{
    return unit_;
}
void AmaProduct::unit(const char* value){
    for (int i = 0; i != 9; i++){
        unit_[i] = value[i];
    }
    unit_[11] = 0;
}
fstream& AmaProduct::store(fstream& file, bool addNewLine)const{
    file.open("file.txt");
    if (file.is_open()){
        file << fileTag_ << "," << sku() << ",";
        file<< name() << ",";//here
        file<< price() << "," << taxed() << "," << quantity() << "," << unit_ << "," << qtyNeeded();
        if (addNewLine){
            file << endl;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return file;
}
```

header file

```
#ifndef SICT_AMAPRODUCT_H__
#define SICT_AMAPRODUCT_H__
#include "Streamable.h"
#include "Product.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include "ErrorMessage.h"
#include "general.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace sict{
class AmaProduct : public Product{
private:
  char fileTag_;
  char unit_[11];
protected:
  ErrorMessage err_;
public:
  AmaProduct(char file='N');
  const char* unit()const;
  void unit(const char* value);
  fstream& store(fstream& file, bool addNewLine = true)const;
  fstream& load(std::fstream& file);
  ostream& write(ostream& os, bool linear)const;
  istream& read(istream& is);
};
}
```

name()

```
const char* Product::name()const{
    return name_;
}
char* name_;
void Product::name(char* name){
    delete[] name_;
    name_= new char[strlen(name)+1];
    strcpy(name_,name);
}
```

if anyone is interested in the other files i will upload them too

Comment: I cannot be bothered with reading all that code. But are you reading the file and using the same pointer

Comment: _"if anyone is interested in the other files i will upload them too"_ Please no! Reduce your sample to a [MCVE]. Step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: added name() so it easier

Comment: is `name_` a `string` or a `char*` ?

Comment: ok !  and in load() you call name(n):  can you provide this function too ?

Comment: How is char* name_ initialized?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities,  but if `cout<<name()` causes a segmentation fault, the most probable cases are:

- `name_` is still nullptr
- `name_` is an invalid pointer (for example if you copied your structure, which doesn't respect the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29))

To make your code more reliable, you could change all `char*`, their  tedious memory allocations and the c-style string operations with `string`.

If you don't, make sure to respect the rule of 3 to avoid shallow copy and pointer issues when copying or copy constructing your struct, and make sure that when you use a fixed size char array, you're sure not to overflow the buffer

Note also that doing this, might overflow the buffer:

```
    file.getline(n, ',');
    name(n);
```

because [`istream::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/), when it has two arguments, takes as second argument the size (here 44, the ascii value of the comma). `file.getline(n, 7, ',')` would be the correct form.

Comment: thank you for you answer, but i also showed how i assign name(n);