# Failure to read input from a file

Tags: c++, fstream

I am unable to read an input from a file. Every time my code reaches strncpy, my code breaks and I am unable to figure out why. The code seems to break at the set name function.

```
fstream& AmaProduct::load(std::fstream& file){
    char s[7];
    char* n;
    n = new char[7];
    double p;
    bool t;
    int q;
    int nn;
    file.open("amaPrd.txt");
    if (file.is_open()){
        file.ignore(2);
        file.getline(s,',');
        cout << s;
        sku(s);
        file.ignore();
        file.getline(n,',');
        name(n);
        file.ignore();
        file >> p;
        price(p);
        file.ignore();
        file >> t;
        taxed(t);
        file.ignore();
        file >> q;
        file.ignore();
        quantity(q);
        file.getline(unit_, ',');
        file.ignore();
        file >> nn;
        qtyNeeded(nn);
    }
    file.close();
    return file;
}
```

This is set here:

```
void Product::sku(char* sku){
    strncpy(sku_,sku,7);
    sku_[7]=0;
}
void Product::price(double price){
    price_=price;
}
void Product::name(char* name){
    delete[] name_;
    name_= new char[strlen(name)+1];
    strcpy(name_,name);
}
void Product::taxed(bool tax){
    taxed_=tax;
}
void Product::quantity(int q){
    quantity_=q;
}
void Product::qtyNeeded(int n){
    qtyNeeded_=n;
```

sku being declared

```
  char sku_[8]
```

I have been working on this for hours but have yet to find a solution.

Comment: Does your code break with a specific error message perchance?

Comment: no, all it says is segmentation fault,

Comment: You have [already been told](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36668283/4944425) that `file.getline(n,',');` is an error and that you should use `file.getline(n, 7, ',');` in your code. Please read the answers users give you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous answer that clearly wasn't correct.

A segmentation fault means your program is trying to access a memory location that doesn't belong to it. In other words, you're writing or reading a pointer that hasn't been (properly) initialized or is out of scope (plus a couple of other options that are less likely here).

You wrote that it crashes at strncpy, and its only reference is in the sku function. You have no "set name" function, but you have a strcpy call in the "name" function. Notice the difference between strncpy and strcpy.

Your function Product::sku(..) copies to sku_ using strncpy, but it is unclear where you are declaring it and whether it is in scope or has been initialized when Product::sku(..) runs. The main function is in a AmaProduct namespace (or class), while the others are in Product. Is that on purpose? In which namespace is sku_ declared?

The Product::name(char* name) function calls strcpy, which assumes that name is a zero-terminated string. Are you sure that it is zero-terminated? If not, it will continue to write and throw a segfault. It is probably also wise to add a maximum number of characters for file.getline() to read. The max number should correspond to the size of the destination buffer.

Also, it is considered unwise to name a function the same as a variable. Having clear and meaningful names makes it easier to see and debug the logic of your code.

Finally, see http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html for more help on debugging.